# How can I integrate Fantomas with MSBuild / dotnet CLI

Tags: .net-core, f#, fantomas

I have F# solutions and projects that build using the .NET Core CLI (`dotnet build`). I would like to format my code using [Fantomas](https://github.com/fsprojects/fantomas) (`dotnet tool run fantomas`).

The problem is that Fantomas does not understand `.sln` or `.fsproj` files. This means that I will need to maintain a script for calling Fantomas on each of my project files, which might become out-of-sync over time.

Is there a mechanism for easily using Fantomas with MSBuild that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with applying fantomas to all .fs files in a certain directory? This way you don't need to involve .sln or .fsproj files.

In case there's a specific file that you don't want to pass by the formatter, you can include it in a .fantomasignore file.